# How to elegantly create a list of optional values?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following function

```
annotate :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal) 
    = concat [
      [m [Name] name],
      if nameReq
        then [m [Operator] "!"]]
        else [],
      case maybeVal of
                      Just v  -> [annotate v]
                      Nothing -> []
    ]
...
```

This seems little elegant. Is there a better way of creating lists of values that might or might not be in it than using `concat` in conjunction with empty lists?

Comment: I actually think this is quite elegant—the only issue is readability. Maybe putting the commas at the start of the line would help?

Comment: You may also want to look at [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe).

Answer (score 3):

As @AJFarmar notes, just cleaning it up would help:

```
annotate :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal)
  = concat
    [ [m [Name] name]
    , if nameReq
        then [m [Operator] "!"]
        else []
    , case maybeVal of
        Just v -> [annotate1 v]
        Nothing -> []
    ]
```

It may also make it clearer to switch from singleton/empty-set to Just/Nothing with the help of `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
annotate' :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate' (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal)
  = catMaybes
    [ Just (m [Name] name)
    , if nameReq
        then Just (m [Operator] "!")
        else Nothing
    , annotate1 <$> maybeVal
    ]
```

Finally, you could consider creating some helper functions and using `<>` if you prefer this syntax:

```
annotate'' :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate'' (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal)
  =    always (m [Name] name)
    <> whenever nameReq (m [Operator] "!")
    <> sometimes (annotate1 <$> maybeVal)
```

with helpers:

```
always :: a -> [a]
always = (:[])
sometimes :: Maybe a -> [a]
sometimes = maybeToList
whenever :: Bool -> a -> [a]
whenever b a = if b then [a] else []
```

Answer (score 3):

When I end up with gangly code like that, I usually clean it up by naming the pieces:

```
annotate :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal) 
    = concat [name, bang, annotation]
    where
        name = [m [Name] name]

        bang | nameReq = [m [Operator] "!"]]
             | otherwise = []

        annotation = case maybeVal of
          Just v  -> [annotate v]
          Nothing -> []
```

Considering that you have a `Maybe` in there, I might also go for `catMaybes` to simplify the `annotation` definition:

```
annotate :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal) 
    = catMaybes [name, bang, annotation]
    where
        name = Just $ m [Name] name

        bang | nameReq = Just $ m [Operator] "!"
             | otherwise = Nothing

        annotation = annotate <$> maybeVal
```

Answer (score 3):

I would tend to generalize the list to any `Alternative`, and exploit the related functions. I find `guard condition *> ...` to be pretty nice in this scenario.

```
annotate :: Alternative f => AST -> f MetaInfo
annotate (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal) =
   pure (m [Name] name)
   <|>
   guard nameReq *> pure (m [Operator] "!")
   <|>
   maybe empty (pure . annotate) maybeVal
```

Alternatively, even with plain lists, using list comprehensions looks nice.

```
annotate :: AST -> [MetaInfo]
annotate (ArgDecl name nameReq maybeVal) =
   [m [Name] name]
   ++
   [ m [Operator] "!" | nameReq ]
   ++
   [ annotate v | Just v <- maybeVal ]
```